# Technical term for accessing an array with an index and square brackets

Tags: objective-c, arrays, terminology, objective-c-literals

What is the term or name of the operation for getting member of an array? For example, this method returns a simple array:

```
- (NSArray*)createArray
{
    NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"unordentliches array", @"beliebiges Value", nil];
    return myArray;
}
```

And I can `NSLog` one of its elements in the following way:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self createArray][1]);
```

Output:

> beliebiges Value

Good, no problem here.

But what do we call this operation: `[self createArray][1]`? One that allows us to -- without first assigning the value to a `NSString` -- simply put this `[1]` right next to the the returned value from a method call and output the value?

```
[self createArray][1];
```

What is the technical term for this?

Comment: I wouldn't be 100% sure of what its called since I've never given it too much thought, but what you're doing there is creating a temporary object. The result of the function call [self createArray] is not stored, so the NSArray is temporary. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are just directly taking the return value of the function and using it.  JQuery has chaining built into most of their calls.  I don't know if that is the official term for that sort of thing.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Sorry, I didn't even know how to call this in order to search for a solution. And the search term "square-bracketed index after an Array" didn't not formulate / fabricate in my mind / imagination as well as it did for the other author linked. Thanks everyone for the time.

Comment: No need to apologize; searching for terminology is indeed hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the element index in parentheses (or brackets in this case) after an array is called “subscripting”.  The index is called a “subscript”.

There is no special name for directly subscripting the array returned by a message without storing the array in a variable first.

Under the covers, the compiler turns the subscripting into another message, like this:

```
[[self createArray] objectAtIndexedSubscript:1];
```

Sending a message directly to the object returned by another message is called “message chaining” or “method chaining”.